# YOLO grids are used to detect multiple objects, then why not treat the whole image as a big grid?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, conv-neural-network, darknet

So I understand that YOLO convolve the whole image but I'm not sure why we have to use grids to detect multiple objects (At least a lot of the articles I've read stated that?). If the network can be designed to detect multiple objects from a grid in a 13*13 grid-image, it should mean it can detect multiple objects from a big 1*1 grid?

Answer (score 3):

So I think this is the answer. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

The grid enables us to detect multiple objects of the SAME class. Lets say its just 1 big grid, and we have 2 classes, the output would be an array of 14 numbers (7 for the first class and 7 for the second class). We cant really have another set of 7 numbers. Whereas if we divide the image into grids SxS, now we are able to make maximum SxS number of object prediction for each of the 2 classes.

I think this is why it's stated that YOLO struggles with objects being close together in a group: because if the grid size is not small enough, you'll have 2 or more center points of the same object class in one grid but you'll only get 1 center-point prediction back.

Comment: Lets say you have 10x10 grid cells which can predict 100 objects, you have one ground truth. If you have one grid cell with 100 objects, you have many permutations of the ground truth which is all equally true. 
For example, you predict an object at index [0] is just as valid as if you predict the object at index [33]. But for your CNN that is very hard to learn as all the connections are hard-wired.